# MYSQL DB to to text file - chartset issues

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I retrieve some text from my MySQL database and then I pass it through tidy like so:

```
$config = array(
                'wrap'                         => 0,
                'lower-literals'               => 1,
                'preserve-entities'            => 1,
                'drop-empty-paras'             => 0,
                'indent'                       => 1,
                'new-blocklevel-tags'          => 'unsubscribe, webversion'
                );

$tidy = new tidy();

$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');

$tidy->cleanRepair();            

$fp = fopen($file_name, 'wb');

fwrite($fp, $tidy->value);

fclose($fp);
```

The contents then gets saved. However, when I view the text file there is some character encoding issues. In the database there is a sring that looks like this `Stan&#146;s`. However, when I view that same string in the text file it looks like this `Stanâ€™s`.

The field in the database and the database itself have a charset of `utf8_general_ci`.

What am I missing?

Comment: The encoding of your script (file) is UTF-8?

Comment: @Alfonso - I am not sure what you mean? The above code is part of a PHP class and doesn't need to have encoding.

Comment: The file has a header coding that makes your editor to save. Generally you can configure which you want to default, and this affects what you write in other documents and in some cases the output to the browser.

Comment: If this is the case the solution of @Tuga should work, although it would be best to save the file (and everyone else) in UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
fwrite($fp, utf8_decode($tidy->value));
```

alternatively, you may try:

```
fwrite($fp, utf8_encode($tidy->value));
```

Also try not setting the character encoding by changing your code to:

```
$tidy->parseString($html, $config);
```

Comment: This makes it worse as it now looks like this `StanÃ¢Â€Â™s`. Encoded twice?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Can you post - for future help - which one helped you ?

Comment: your first suggestion helped me.